# use var from function.php file into scripts.js file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function.php code simple one:

```
$var = "7000";
```

and I have another file script.js:

```
var Price = <?php echo $var ?>;
```

now it works when this code in the same file.

but when I separate the files its doesn't.

any suggestions?

Comment: The PHP variables are not globally accessible through all pages - only in the files where the PHP file is loaded before executing. They must be in the same file, or you must load from that PHP file first.

Comment: file1.php: `<?php $var = 7000;` - file2.php: `<?php include('file1.php'); <script>var Price = <?= json_encode($var) ?></script>`

Comment: What @GrumpyCrouton said, or make an AJAX request to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script called `price.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/javascript"); // As suggested by Mark Eriksson
$var =  "7000";
?>
const PRICE = <?php echo $var; ?>;
```

Now you can reference this JavaScript block on any HTML page:

```
<script src="price.php"></script>
```

You will have a global JavaScript variable (constant) called `PRICE`.

Do you need variable prices? No problem, you can pass a value as a parameter, for example:

```
<script src="price.php?price=8500"></script>
```

And in your `price.php`, you change it to:

```
<?php
    $var =  $_GET["price"];
?>
 const PRICE = <?php echo $var; ?>;
```

Your HTML page still gets a constant named `PRICE`.

Comment: You can add `header(‘Content-type: text/javascript’);` to the `price.php` file to make the server think it’s requesting a JS file

Comment: @MarkEriksson Sure! I've forgot that! Edited and included your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by GrumpyCrouton in his comment to you, variables out of one file can be read in another by including them

```
<?php 
include('file1.php'); // include the file where the variable is defined
<script>
var Price = <?= json_encode($var) ?>; // in javascript code export the variable to js usign json
</script>
```

It is always safe to use json_encode and dump the variable directly into js no need to encapsulate it any more then that, I would add a semicolon at the end but that is more of a personal preference in this day and age.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you want to access some PHP variables, then you need to use AJAX.
Its quite simple.

Do this inside function.php file

```
<?php
$var = "7000";
// Put your price into array to form it into JSON format further
$data = ["price" => $var];
return json_encode($data);
```

And following in your JS file.

```
let xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'function.php', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        // Your final result
        var Price = data.price;
    }
}
xhr.send();
```